# Launch JavaScript from Website / Exit Application

Tags: c#, javascript, process

Long story short, it's about a Windows Form Application with a WebBrowser control. The application opens a website, fills in username and password, logs in, launches a vpn client (exe) by executing a javascript. Once the vpn client is successfully started, the application should exit. The first half is working fine.

I'd like to check if the vpn client is running, if so, it should close the my application, otherwise wait for the exe to start.

```
private void LaunchJS()
        {
            HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
            Object js = doc.InvokeScript("launchJS");
            label1.Text = "complete";
        }
```

.

```
if (label1.Text == ("complete"))
            {
            bool prc = false;
            while (!prc)
            {
                foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses())
                {
                    if (clsProcess.ProcessName.Contains("JS_plugin"))
                    {
                        prc = true;
                        Application.Exit();
                    }
                }
            }
            }
```

The Problem I'm experiencing is that the javascript launch is unsuccessful, when I enable the second part (check process) of the code. The java script isn't executed, the program will never launch and the check process goes into an infinite loop.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: make sure there are not any backslashes to you javascript file http://blogs.msdn.com/b/freeassociations/archive/2005/05/19/420059.aspx

Answer (score 0):

doing the process check in a separate thread has resolved my issue.

```
private void GetPRo()
{
    if (label1.Text == ("complete"))
    {
        bool prc = false;
        while (!prc)
        {
            foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                if (clsProcess.ProcessName.Contains("JS_plugin"))
                {
                    prc = true;
                    Application.Exit();
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

.

```
Thread CloseApp = new Thread(new ThreadStart(GetPro));
CloseApp.Start();
```